# Cutomize grid layout rows size

Tags: user-interface, go, fyne

I'm trying to have a grid layout with rows in which first row is a `GroupWithScroller` and second row is a `ContainerWithLayout` and has only two buttons, `quit` and `Ok`, so the second row's height must be short, but I don't know how to resize any of those. This is what I've tried:

```golang
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Title")
    var (
        quitButton = widget.NewButton("Quit", func() {
            a.Quit()
        })

        okButton = widget.NewButton("Ok", func() {
            confirmed = true
            a.Quit()
        })
    )
    var (
        filesBox = widget.NewGroupWithScroller("Another Title",)
        buttonsBox = fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewAdaptiveGridLayout(2), quitButton, okButton)
    )
    for _, file := range files {
        var fileCheck = check{
            checked: false,
            label: filepath.Base(file),
        }
        storeChecks = append(storeChecks, &fileCheck)
        filesBox.Append(widget.NewCheck(fileCheck.label, fileCheck.toggle))
    }
    w.SetContent(
        fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(
            layout.NewGridLayoutWithRows(2),
            filesBox,
            buttonsBox,
            ),
        )

    w.Resize(fyne.Size{
        Width:  320,
        Height: 480,
    })
    w.ShowAndRun()
```

But the result window seems to halve the height for each row:

[image: result window]

How to change second row's height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GridLayout is designed to keep all elements the same size. If you want the buttons to be minimum height at the bottom you probably want BorderLayout instead - setting the buttons to be in the bottom space should do what you describe.

Comment: Well, before I come up with grid, I tried BorderLayout, and placed buttons at bottom, but the problem is when I put list of check items at top, its height is as small as height of buttons, and even `filesBox.Resize(fyne.Size{...})` doesn't seem to change its size. [here](https://imgur.com/YhIeqmU) is what I mean.

Comment: The top, bottom, left and right of border layout all shrink to their minimum - height for top and bottom or width for left and right - that is how it is designed. Any items in the container that are not listed will be in the central part and expand to fill.

Comment: Resizing items manually within a layout will not make any difference, as the layout is managing size and position for you. I'd recommend reading the Layout tour, hopefully that explains it better than I can https://tour.fyne.io/layout/